# How do I setup this javascript regex match function?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input textbox that runs a js function on the keyup event to match for a valid string (domain name pattern match, the regex was found on here).

I wrote the if statements to test whether the input is a valid pattern first and then more than 3 characters long.

Apparently, my ifs don't work like I wanted them to.  When the input has 3 or more characters, it is fine.

But if the input is less than 3 characters, it fails the pattern regex.

Example: if the input box has "dd" (no quotes), the function will alert that I have an incorrect pattern when it SHOULD alert that the input is less than 3 characters long.

From the alert statement included, there is no extra spaces or characters in the input value.

```
<input id="quick" type="text" size="20" onKeyUp="test()"></input>
```

the function test is

```
function test(){

   var liveword = document.getElementById("quick").value;
   var valid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$/;
  alert("xxx"+liveword+"xxx");

    if (liveword.match(valid))
   {
        if (liveword.length < 3)
        {
        alert ('word less than 3');
        }
        else {
    alert ('word more than 3');
            }
     }//outside if

     else {
         alert('enter correct pattern');

     }  

} //close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your pattern is currently written, nothing under 3 letters can ever match it. Your regex says "Find any alphanumeric, followed by at least one alphanumeric or dash or underscore, followed by a final alphanumeric."

I think you might actually want some optional matching in there instead. With:

```
var valid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]?$/;
```

You will match on any alphanumeric, even if there is only one character. Really though, the above is the same as simply saying:

```
var valid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]*$/;
```

Note that both would still potentially match on something like `a-`. If that is not an intended match (i.e. you want to require a terminating alphanumeric when hyphen or dash are used), then go with:

```
var valid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$/;
```

Which says "Find one alphanumeric. If it has characters following it, it can be followed by zero or more characters that are alphanumeric or hyphens or underscores, so long as the last character is alphanumeric."

Comment: Hi JGB, thanks for the regex code.  I got the code from another post and it appeared to work independently at first, but I guess it does not work in conjunction with the if statements that I included.  Regex is one of those kind of things that you either understand it or you don't, and I don't.

Comment: @jamex: You're welcome. Regex throws a lot of people, so you're in good company. Were you able to get the effect you wanted with one of the regex patterns I provided?

Comment: thank you, I just tested it (your second regex), and it works perfectly.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your first if is testing to see if the pattern is matching, regardless of length. If it is a good match, then you check length. If not, you alert "enter correct pattern".

You want to do this:

```
if( liveword.length < 3 )
    alert( 'too short' )

else
{
    // check patterns, alert good or bad
}
```

---

Edit

Your code, refactored:

```
function test(){

    var liveword = document.getElementById("quick").value;
    var valid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$/;
    alert("xxx"+liveword+"xxx");

    if( liveword.length < 3 )
        alert( 'word less than 3' );

    else
    {
        if( liveword.match(valid) )
            alert( 'good match')

        else
            alert( 'bad match' )
    } 

} //close
```

Comment: Hi winter, thanks. Your code works, but I intentionally wanted to check for valid characters first before I check for length.  I don't want the code to check for length if the input is invalid.

Comment: @Jamex: Why? Checking for length is almost certainly a faster operation than checking for validity.

Comment: @JGB, if the user enters "#" or ., as the first character, you don't want to wait for the user to enter the next character before you give a warning, that way, the user does not have to hit a bunch of backspaces.

Comment: @Jamex: makes sense then. I believe my answer will do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the `if (liveword.match(valid))` succeeds then that means the word is at least three characters long since your regex requires at least three characters. The `if (liveword.length < 3)` check will therefore never succeed located where it is. You need to move it to an `else` clause so that you check the length if the word *doesn't* match:

```
if (liveword.match(valid)) {
    alert ('word 3 or more');
}
else if (liveword.length < 3) {
    alert ('word less than 3');
}
else {
    alert('enter correct pattern');
}
```

Comment: Hi John, I don't think the regex pattern contains the check for length.  It is the "if" statement that is checking for length.

Comment: @ John, sorry, I lack of regex knowledge led me to misunderstood your answer.